# corse tree identification

Tags: species-identification, botany

My nosy belling-cat was asking itself what kind of mediterranean tree/fruit is seen on the pictures below. Location is Corsica, St. Florent - late June.

Extra points on nutrition factors in case of adability ;)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a [loquat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loquat), native to China, family Roseaceae.  Latin binomial is *Eriobotrya japonica*.